# Create a C++ implementation of Matlab histcounts function

Tags: c++, matlab, histogram, histogram2d

I want to program a function in C++ which does the same thing as the function `histcounts` in Matlab, but I don't get the right edges.

```
[V, edges]=histcounts(Vector,10);
```

I found this post : [implementing matlab hist() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329193/implementing-matlab-hist-in-c) and I created a function which I thought should work. How do I get the same edges in my function as in `histcounts`?

My Code :

```
int n =10;
double histogrammdistance = (ceil(*max_element(std::begin(Vector), std::end(Vector)))-floor(*min_element(std::begin(Vector), std::end(Vector))))/n;
vector<double> edges;
double minY = *min_element(std::begin(Vector), std::end(Vector));

for (int i = 0 ;i <=n; i++)
{
    edges.push_back(floor(minY) +  histogrammdistance * i);
}
```

So My Problem right now is :

i have this Vector = [-37,0329218106996 -26,9722222222222   -34,0823045267490   -33,0987654320988   -39 -35,0658436213992   -30,8061224489796   -36,0493827160494   -38,0164609053498   -12]

Matlab creates these edges :

edges [-40  -37,2000000000000   -34,4000000000000   -31,6000000000000   -28,8000000000000   -26 -23,2000000000000   -20,4000000000000   -17,6000000000000   -14,8000000000000   -12,0000000000000]

But my Program doesn't use -40 to calculate the binwidth..because the minimum number is -39 and not -40. Also if i change -39 to -38.5... matlab is still picking -40

**1, Question** : Why is Matlab taking -40 ... and has sb an idea how this could be implemented ?

i created now a very simpel Vector with [1 2 3 4 5] if i take 15 as bin number i get this as solution [1 1.27 1.54 1.81 ...] bit if i take 13 as bin number it doesn*t start with the min number 1 :/ it starts with [0,90 1,2 1,54 1,8 2,18....]

**2. Question** : do sb know why it took 0.90 ??

Comment: It looks like Matlab is taking the floor of the min value. I'm not sure what it does with the max value, you'd have to give it a non-integer max and see.

Comment: @beaker Oh .. Jes you 're right .. It seems that he is using also floor for the maximum :) but now i have another Problem :S i created now a very simpel Vector with [1 2 3 4 5] if i take 15 as bin number i get this as solution [1 1.27 1.54 1.81 ...] bit if i take 13 as bin number it doesn*t start with the min number 1 :/ it starts with [0,90 1,2 1,54 1,8 2,18....] do you or sb else have an idea why it took 0.90 ??

Comment: Can you add the updates to the question itself? Also, I would expect that Matlab would either use `ceil` for the maximum, or just leave it alone. If you use `floor` you'd miss counting a non-integer max value.

Comment: i updated the code in the question with floor and ceil ... and also changed the question .. maybe you have an idea to Qustion 1 and 2 :/

Comment: I have no idea, but it would probably help if you put the full vectors of bin edges rather than cutting them off.